# Populating array with response from nested AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I have an array that I would like to fill with responses from AJAX calls like so:

```
var dict = [];

function fillArray(){
  $.post('getUsersOnline.php', function(phpReturnVal){
    // ...
    for(var i = 0; i < phpReturnVal.length; i++){
        $.get("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams"  , function(data){
          dict[data.key] = data;
    });
  });
}

function doStuff(){
  // dict is empty or undefined here
}
```

How would I fill dict with objects so that I could retrieve them inside doStuff()? Currently, I am able to insert stuff into dict but when I try accessing dict outside the fillArray() function, I get an empty dict variable since I'm assuming the GET call is asynchronous and doesn't happen until after all the JS code has executed...

Comment: Can include  _"but when I try accessing the array variable outside the fillArray() function, I get an empty dict variable"_  `js`  ?

Comment: How/where do you access `dict`?

Comment: edited the question once more.

Answer (score 1):

So, `dict` is an `object` that has no `push` method. You'd need `dict=[];` If you had to have `{}`, then you'd need key:value pairs to populate it, such as:

```
dict[key] = value;
```

Comment: Ok, I guess my question may have been unclear. I am (mostly) aware of the syntax required to insert key:value pairs but my question is meant to address the issue of storing data with the asynchronous call in my code.

Comment: Sure, what issue are we talking about? And also plz use `var` here - `for(var i = 0;`

Comment: Accessing the dict variable from outside of the fillArray() function. Currently, it is null from anywhere else. I've updated the question to include more info.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to keep track of the number of calls that you are doing in that for loop and fire a callback function once they are all complete. I'm not totally confident about your current solution, with calling an indefinite amount of ajax requests, but I also don't fully understand the scope of your problem or the server that you're talking to.

So basically you will have to do something like this with what you have currently:

```
var dict = [],
  requestsCompleted = 0;


function dictFilled() {
  // do something with your dict variable;
}

function fillArray(){
  $.post('getUsersOnline.php', function(phpReturnVal){
    // ...
    for(var i = 0; i < phpReturnVal.length; i++){
        $.get("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams"  , function(data){
          dict[data.key] = data;
          requestsCompleted++;
          if (requestsCompleted === phpReturnVal.length) {
            dictFilled();
          }
    });
  });
}
```

This haven't been tested, but basically you will have to define a function that will have access to the array that you are filling and call it once all you asynchronous requests finish successfully. For tasks like this though I recommend you take a look at [jQuery's Deferred API](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/). There is always a chance that one of those requests will fail and your application should know what to do if that happens.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm assuming the GET call is asynchronous and doesn't happen until
>   after all the JS code has executed...

Appear correct.

---

Try

```
var dict = [];

function fillArray() {
  // return jQuery promise object
  return $.post('getUsersOnline.php', function(phpReturnVal){
    // ...
    for(var i = 0; i < phpReturnVal.length; i++) {
        // call same `url` `phpReturnVal.length` times here ?,
        // returning same `data` response at each request ?,
        // populating, overwriting `dict` with same `data.key` property ?
        $.get("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams"  , function(data) {
          dict[data.key] = data;
        });
    }; // note closing `}` at `for` loop
    // return value
    return dict
  });
}

function doStuff(data) {
   // `data`:`dict`, promise value returned from `fillArray`
   console.log(data);
}

fillArray().then(doStuff, function error(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)
});
```

---

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
var response = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3
};
var obj = {};
var dict = [];

function fillArray() {
  return $.when(arr).then(function(phpReturnVal) {
    for (var i = 0; i < phpReturnVal.length; i++) {
      // return same `response` here ?
      $.when(response).then(function(data) {
        dict[arr[i]] = data;
      });
    };
    return dict
  });
}

function doStuff(data) {
  console.log(data)
}

fillArray().then(doStuff, function error(err) {
  console.log(err)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```